# How do i restart a timer after a clearInterval() in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have a timer, and when i use `clearInterval(this.temporizador)` the time stops. I want to restart the timer from 0 when i use `resetState()`, but its not working. What am i doing wrong?

```
componentWillMount() {
        console.log("DEBUG: componentWillMount");
        this.generateCardArray();
        this.shuffleFunction();
        this.temporizador = setInterval(() => {
          const { seconds, minutes } = this.state
          const timeformat = (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds)
          if (seconds < 59) {
            this.setState(({ seconds }) => ({
              seconds: seconds + 1
            }))
          }

          if (seconds === 59) {
              this.setState(({ minutes }) => ({
                minutes: minutes + 1,
                seconds: 0
              }))

          }

          if (minutes === 60){
          clearInterval(this.temporizador)
          alert("Time's up! Game is restarting")
          window.location.reload(true);}

          this.setState({time: timeformat })
        }, 1000)

      }

  resetState(){
    this.setState({
      cardArray: [],
      matchedcardArray: [],
      cardSelection:[],
      attempts: 0,
      seconds: 1,
      minutes: 0,
      time: "00:00" , 
      cardsMatched: 0,
      showEnd: false
    })
    this.generateCardArray();
    this.shuffleFunction();
    setInterval(this.temporizador,1000);
  }
```

Comment: There is nothing that recreates an interval by the id. You need to rerun the code that made the interval

Comment: You can restart the interval by placing the initial `this.temporizador = setInterval()` code in its own function, then call that function after calling generateCardArray and shuffleFunction.

Comment: Interval (or timeout) id are only used to clear it and not to restart it. You have to create another one using the same function as first attribute

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to just start up the interval again so move the code into its own function and call it.

```
runTimer() {

    this.temporizador = setInterval(() => {
      const { seconds, minutes } = this.state
      const timeformat = (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds)
      if (seconds < 59) {
        this.setState(({ seconds }) => ({
          seconds: seconds + 1
        }))
      }

      if (seconds === 59) {
          this.setState(({ minutes }) => ({
            minutes: minutes + 1,
            seconds: 0
          }))

      }

      if (minutes === 60){
      clearInterval(this.temporizador)
      alert("Time's up! Game is restarting")
      window.location.reload(true);}

      this.setState({time: timeformat })
    }, 1000)
}
```

so in the componentWillMount and resetState, call the method.